# Discord Py Sending Live Python Output

Tags: discord, console, discord.py, output

I'm currently working on a text-to-image generation bot and I'd like it to send live messages with information about the time remaining in the generation, iteration, and speed at which it's generating, all can be found in the console but I have no idea how to send console output to discord.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `print("output")` to print into the console.

You can send the message to Discord via `Messageable#send()`
For example sending to a channel would be

```py
await channel.send(content="content")
```

You can get the `Messageable` in a lot of ways

```py
# In a cog
channel = ctx.channel
# In a cog you can directly use ctx.send() however

# In a on_message event
channel = message.channel
```

Now simply, send whatever you are printing to the console to Discord

```py
# Printing to console
print("hello world")

# Sending to message
await channel.send(content="hello world")
```

That approach can be a bit "spammy", so a better practice is to **edit** the message instead

```py
# channel.send() returns the message

# Printing
print("status update")

# Sending message
message = await channel.send(content="status update")

# [Image generation code]

# Printing
print("new status update")

# Editing message
await message.edit(content="new status update")
```

Comment: In theory that would work if I knew the variable that was being printed, the variable I want printed comes from an import that's why I was looking fro a message to capture all output

Comment: Maybe perhaps show the code you have already in your post?